# Code editor with black background and color text?

Tags: editor, color-scheme

There's a code editor that I see everywhere that has a black background with very vivid colored text. Which editor is this? I left an example of what it looks like below.

https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/21/2313316/a3e0c238-a307-11e3-81bb-d70b4675c759.gif

The code editor in the background is what it looks like. I see it everywhere and I never can find it anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Many IDEs allow you to change the color scheme, you should check in the documentation of you favourite one

Answer (score 3):

This is Atom, the new text editor by GitHub.
You can find more info here : http://atom.io/

Answer (score 2):

There are several editors out there... Depending on what OS you're using, you could use any of the following:

Mac OS X -

 - TextMate

 - Coda

 - PHPStorm

 - WebStorm

Windows -

 - PHPStorm

 - WebStorm

 - Intype

And there are many many more out there. Each of these as well as others will allow you to change the display to be "Dark with Vivid Code".